# Limiting concurrent threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm using threads in a program that uploads files over sftp.  The number of files that could be upload can potentially be very large or very small.  I'd like to be able to have 5 or less simultaneous uploads, and if there's more have them wait.  My understanding is usually a conditional variable would be used for this, but it looks to me like that would only allow for 1 thread at a time.

```
cv = ConditionVariable.new

t2 = Thread.new {
  mutex.synchronize {
    cv.wait(mutex)
    upload(file)
    cv.signal
  }
}
```

I think that should tell it to wait for the cv to be available the release it when done.  My question is how can I do this allowing more than 1 at a time while still limiting the number?

edit: I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows from the 1 click installer

Comment: Ruby version you are using is important for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ThreadPool instead. See [Deadlock in ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81788/deadlock-in-threadpool/82777#82777) (the accepted answer, specifically).

Answer (score 1):

A word of caution -- there is no real concurrency in Ruby unless you are using JRuby. Also, exception in thread will freeze main loop unless you are in debug mode.

```
require "thread"

POOL_SIZE = 5

items_to_process = (0..100).to_a

message_queue = Queue.new

start_thread = 
  lambda do
    Thread.new(items_to_process.shift) do |i|
      puts "Processing #{i}"
      message_queue.push(:done)
    end
  end

items_left = items_to_process.length

[items_left, POOL_SIZE].min.times do
  start_thread[]
end

while items_left > 0 
  message_queue.pop
  items_left -= 1
  start_thread[] unless items_left < POOL_SIZE
end
```

Comment: This is not true. Version 1.9.2 of MRI uses a native/kernel threads with a GIL. It's not as effective as the JRuby or MacRuby threads, but they aren't the green threads that 1.8.7 has. In the case of doing IO work (like the question implies) 1.9.2 threads are quite useful (just look at Typhoeus if you don't believe me).

Comment: @coreyward Agree. I have always thought that even in 1.8.7 IO is in fact done in parallel. Hard to believe that Ruby uses blocking calls to IO system that freeze scheduler. Besides, thread pools can be used to limit socket usage, file handles etc.